# simple ajax span question

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

```
<span name = "menu">
<!-- javascript here -->
<!-- content called via ajax --> 
</span>


<span name = "content"> 
<!-- content called via ajax --> 
<!-- changed by buttons from the menu-->
</span>
```

Does anyone know how to display contents in the content span using ajax generated menu from the menu span? If I'm not wrong, selecting a span can only happen within the same span. Is there something like parentpage.span like mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you can access the `span` as you have it currently using `document.getElementsByName("content")`. However, it would probably be easier to give the `span` an `id`, then do something like this in your AJAX success function:

```
document.getElementById("spanID").innerHTML = ajaxResponse.responseText;
```

Comment: I used id, sorry for the confusion. My question was, is it posible to use document.getElementById("spanID").innerHTML within a span to change contents in a different span. Does spanID work like a global variable or more like a local variable in a function?

Comment: You can use `getElementById` anywhere, providing the element you are looking for exists on the page at that point in time. `spanID` is not a variable, it's just a string that you pass in to the function. The `document` object is accessible from any JS function.

Comment: I get the role of spanID. I'm just asking if it is accessible anywhere like a global variable.

Comment: when i tried to display something in a span from within a different span, it does not display anything. the code works fine if i just take it out of the span.

Answer (score 0):

It's a better idea to give those span's ID that you can hook into:

```
<span name="menu" id="menu">
    <!-- Content called via Ajax -->
</span>
```

Then you could use

```
var div = document.getElementById('menu');
alert(div.name);
```

I would suggest against having JS code run inside the element because IE can puke all over that.

Comment: I used id, sorry for the confusion. My question was, is it posible to use document.getElementById("spanID").innerHTML within a span to change contents in a different span. Does spanID work like a global variable or more like a local variable in a function?